# Multipart Form Submit to Ruby Method Using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Within my RoR application I have a dataTable with a button that triggers a Bootstrap modal that contains a multipart form. I am having difficulty passing the uploaded file (in this case an image) to my RoR method through an AJAX call. I've tried using the `formData()` method but my AJAX call doesn't even make it to my method which it previously would without incorporating `formData()`. I could accomplish my task by incorporating the form into the actual view but I need this form to be part of a modal. Any help is greatly appreciated. I also have an issue with not being able to verify CSRF token authenticity but that may be a different beast I have to tackle.

`HTML`

```
<form id="upload_form" name="upload_form" action="/admin/jobs/job_screenshot"   
method="post" multipart="true">
  <input id="j_id" type="hidden" value="538f7b5a9bb8f9a5ba000045">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <ul>
      <li>Select Screenshot to Upload</li>
      <li>
        <input accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" type="file">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="ss_submit" class="btn button btn-success" type="submit" value="Upload Screenshot">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("submit", "#upload_form", function(e) {
  var formData;
  formData = new FormData($(this)[1]);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/admin/jobs/job_screenshot",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").attr("content"));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Is this image going to be associated with a data model? What are you doing for storage?

Comment: Yes, image will be associated with a domain model which will store multiple screenshots. In another method I am already handling the storage just need help with passing the file to the method.